# Representing unitary matrices as permutations in some basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

A permutation matrix $P_s$ can be defined on an orthonormal set of vectors $ v_1,  \ldots v_n$ as, $$ P_s = \sum_i v_i v^\dagger _{s(i)} $$ where $s$ is an element of the symmetric group on $n$ elements.

Can a unitary matrix on an $n$ dimensional vector space be represented as a permutation matrix in some basis ? (Up to some overall phase factor.)

Comment: No. Permutation matrices have eigenvalues which are roots of unity, and most unitary matrices don't, even up to an overall phase.

Comment: Of course! But what if we restrict ourselves to unitary matrices that have eigenvalues from the roots of unity?

Comment: An additional constraint is that the eigenvalues of a permutation matrix are grouped according to the cycles of the corresponding permutation: an $n$-cycle contributes eigenvalues all of the $n^{th}$ roots of unity. So e.g. the eigenvalues also need to have the property that if some primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity is an eigenvalue then every $n^{th}$ root of unity is an eigenvalue. This constraint about being able to group eigenvalues into cycles is necessary and sufficient.